# BGP route traffic from iBGP over eBGP instead

Tags: bgp

Topology of the network:
[image]

```
R1 and R2 are iBGP 
R3 and R4 are iBGP

R1 - R3 eBGP
R2 - R4 eBGP
```

I want R1 to direct the traffic for R2 to go through R3, R4 then to R2 and then back the same way in reverse.

I have tried manipulating LOCAL_PREFERENCE on R3/R4 but when I check the `ip bgp` there is still only one route to R2.

All routers are `next-hop-self` to their iBGP neighbor.

Output config `show ip bgp 10.2.0.0`

Output for R1 is 
`Local 2.2.2.2 from 2.2.2.2 Origin IGP, localpref 100, valid, internal, best`

Output on R3 with the inclusion of locpref is:
`4.4.4.4 from 4.4.4.4 Origin IGP, localpref 200, valid, internal, best`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default R1 will drop the route to R2 received form R3 because the AS path contains R1's AS.  On cisco you can use allowas-in to stop this default behaviour though I've never done this myself and I guess you could get yourself in a right pickle if you were to implement it wrong.

Comment: using allowas-in opens up the potential for alternate routes, thank you